# Populating UITableView with results of NSURLSession

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, single-responsibility-principle

So I'm trying to populate a tableView with the results of an api call. I have a feeling this is some weird architectural thing I'm missing (back-end web dev/game dev) and I can not for the life of me figure this out.

I have a few files interacting in this dance:

My `DashboardViewController.swift` is responsible for calling `StatusListViewController.swift`.

It does this through `StatusHelper.swift`, who's purpose is to make and handle the REST call and JSON deserializing.

I have a tableview in `StatusListViewController.swift` who has a delegate and a datasource each in different files (for clean code).

At the end of the `StatusHelper` method call, I call `presentViewController` from Dashboard to `StatusList`.

Here are relevant snippets from the files:

DashboardViewController.swift:

```
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func showStatuses(sender: UIButton) {
        StatusHelper.getStatusesList(ViewController: self)
    }
```

StatusListViewController.swift:

```
class StatusListViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var statusTable: UITableView!
    let cellDescriptor = "Status"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.statusTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellDescriptor)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

StatusHelper.swift:

```
class StatusHelper {
    class func getStatusesList(ViewController vc: UIViewController)
    {
        // Standard NSURLSession datawithtask call
        // Append items to statusList from API results
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nvc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StatusList") as! StatusListViewController
        nvc.statusTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Status")
        nvc.statusTable.dataSource = StatusListDataSource(StatusList: statusList)
        nvc.statusTable.delegate = StatusListDelegate()
        vc.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

StatusListDataSource.swift:

```
class StatusListDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var statusList: [Status]
    let cellDescriptor = "Status"

    init(StatusList sl: [Status])
    {
        self.statusList = sl
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.statusList.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellDescriptor) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.statusList[indexPath.row].label
        return cell
    }
}
```

StatusListDelegate.swift:

```
class StatusListDelegate: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("Selected \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

So when trying to use the `statusTable` property of the `UIViewController`, it's unwrapping a nil an throwing an exception. I tried adding a `statusTable = UITableView()` but that didn't work (also that doesn't feel right since I already bound it to the Interface Builder item).

So maybe there's an architectural mindset change, but what I'd like to end up with is:

- Separation of concerns: There are tutorials on throwing everything into one giant `UIViewController`, but I'm not interested in this.
- An understanding of how the application flow is supposed to work regarding switching views in response to a `NSURLSession` call (am I supposed to be calling presentView in the helper method? or should I be loading the view containing the tableview (I get an exception doing this) before making the rest api call)
- Any resource to look to in the future. I've seen tutorials for either slamming all of this in a `UIViewController`, or a tutorial for separating datasource and delegate out, but no tutorial where they make rest api calls and load another table view with separate datasource and delegates

Thanks!

Edit: I'm using xcode 6.3 beta with swift 1.2 (for the chain optional unwrapping in my json deserialization).